# AJAX & Json get function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am creating a "Garment checker" using ajax and I would like the user to put the ID into the input followed by a request to the URL. which prints out the code if it exists. The code below just isn't doing the job as I would like it to although I think that it is almost correct. Can anybody see my mistakes or point me in the right direction please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";


    $('#lookupForm')
      .removeAttr('onsubmit')
      .submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var target = document.getElementById('garmentID');
        if(target.value.length > 0) {
          fetchData(target.value);
        }
      });
    });

        function fetchData(garmentID) {
          var url = 'http://staging.me-tail.net/api/3.0/retailer/4/garmentsAvailable?guid=' + applicationID;

          $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

            var appDetails = data.AvailableSkus[0];
            $('#garmentTitle').val(appDetails.AvailableSkus);
      });
        }
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question and what isn't working?

Comment: is "applicationID" defined in the url ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `data.AvailableSkus` seems to be an array, you don't want to pass the collection as the value to `#garmentTitle`.

You're most likely after a property (if the array contains objects) or the actual element:

```
//if typeof appDetails.AvailableSkus[0] is string or number:
$('#garmentTitle').val(appDetails.AvailableSkus[0]);
```

or

```
//if typeof appDetails.AvailableSkus[0] is an object:
$('#garmentTitle').val(appDetails.AvailableSkus[0].someProp);
```

> value
>   Type: String or Array
>   A string of text or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to set as selected/checked.

Comment: Still not getting an output. This is as far as I have got.http://jsfiddle.net/Lxbb9/3/

Comment: @user2822683 THe issue seems to be that it's a cross domain call.

Comment: DO you know what I am missing here?

Comment: @user2822683 What serverside language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This link provides output properly

```
http://staging.me-tail.net/api/3.0/retailer/4/garmentsAvailable?guid=5
```

are you sure "applicationID" is setted before ?

```
var url = 'http://staging.me-tail.net/api/3.0/retailer/4/garmentsAvailable?guid=' + applicationID;
```

Any error message in firebug console ?